# warning CS0618: 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTipBase.ManualClose' is obsolete

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik

Все привет. В нашем командном проекте teamcity выдает следующий варнинг

> warning CS0618: 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTipBase.ManualClose' is
>   obsolete: 'This property is obsolete. Please use
>   HideEvent="ManualClose" instead.'

В некоторых местах я изменил как рекомендовано teamcity. Но есть места где HideEvent уже используется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем заменить ManualClose="true"

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как вы поняли *Please use HideEvent="ManualClose" instead.* и что вы подразумеваете под выражением: *Но есть места где HideEvent уже используется*?

Comment: я понимаю это так : teamcity предлагает использовать HideEvent="ManualClose" вместо ManualClose="true". Извините, не правльно выразился, когда писал о других местах. Здесь я подразумавел набор свойств элемента, что свойству HideEvent уже присвоено значение в элементе

Comment: @ВладимирОлейников ворнинг возникает из-за упоминания свойства ManualClose. Если ли при это еще упоминание HideEvent или нет - компилятору не приципиально. Если есть - удалите упоминание ManualClose и все пройдет.

Comment: Вы хотить сказать что ManualClose="true" ничего не делает и ни на что не влияет?

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор советует вам заменить вызовы устаревшего `ManualClose` на новый `HideEvent="ManualClose"`. А не наоборот.

При этом копмилятор не проверяет, задано ли у вас свойство `HideEvent` - предупреждение показывается только из-за упоминания в поде `ManualClose`.

Удалите его, и предупреждение пропадет.

Это Warning, так что игнорировать его или нет - на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Но задача стоит избавиться от него, чтоб лог был чистым

Comment: @ВладимирОлейников да, избавляйтесь - замена ManualClose на HideEvent="ManualClose" уберет warning.

Comment: а если HideEven уже присвоено значение HideEvent="LeaveTargetAndToolTip" ?

Comment: @ВладимирОлейников его и оставьте

Comment: значить ManualClose="true" тепер ни на что не влияет и его удаление соответственно ничего в функционале не изменит??

Comment: @ВладимирОлейников два варианта - или он ни на что не влияет при заданном  HideEvent="LeaveTargetAndToolTip", или он неявно заменяет  HideEvent="LeaveTargetAndToolTip" на HideEvent="ManualClose" + выдает предупреждение. попробуйте удалить и посмотреть что получится

Comment: @ВладимирОлейников это два способа задать поведение - новый и старый. вы используете их одновременно. один из них, скорее всего, не работает :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Решила просто использовать HideEvent="ManualClose"